# Moving Database from one availability Group to another sitting on different SQL Instance

Tags: sql-server, alwayson

We have Always on configured with Three Cluster Node ( 2 in same data center for HA and other one in different data center for DR). Each of the Node has three SQL instance on them. We have created one AG on per instance. Now we have situation , where we would like to move database from one AG group to another one which are sitting on different SQL instance.

**Database migration from one AG group to another**

**Image Below**

[image: Screen Shot]

We would like to move the DB 4 and DB 5 from AG 1 (Instance 1) on Node 1 to AG 2 Primary (Instance two ) on node two. Is this something achievable? if yes, please help us with steps. Any help or guidance is much appreciated. Note: - Database already exists on instance two in AG1 secondary. So, we do not require (or want) to copy the database to instance two on node.

Answer (score 1):

Always On availability groups support making backup on your secondary replicas. You can first create a maintenance plan for your back up task and then restore the databases and log backups on the instances. Please refer to [Offload supported backups to secondary replicas of an availability group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/active-secondaries-backup-on-secondary-replicas-always-on-availability-groups?view=sql-server-2017).

Note that you can only perform copy-only full backups for your databases. But for performing log back up, the COPY_ONLY option is not supported for secondary replicas.

Answer (score 0):

You can swap databases to any AG you want however you need to remove it from the current AG before doing so.

I would suggest easiest route is to replicate your current AG to the target instance you want to move to. Once the data has synchronized, simply failover to it as your new primary. Then remove the previous replica off of Node 1 if you no longer require it there. You can then also add new replicas to whichever other systems you want.

Other option is to take the backup,logs and restore on your target node, then add as replica and remove the replica from node 1.